# How To Install Pervasive ODBC on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: odbc, pervasive-sql

It's not often I can't find any answer to a question online, but this is one of those times. I'm trying to install an OBDC driver on Linux for Pervasive SQL (PSQL). Does anyone know how or where I can find this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of Pervasive you're using, the ODBC driver is part of the Client install.  For Pervasive PSQL v11, the client is available an RPM or as a TAR for 32 bit or 64 bit at http://www.pervasive.com/database/Home/Products/PSQLv11.aspx with instructions at http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=getstart/04nstunx.13.1.html.

UPDATE: As of October 2021, available downloads are at https://esd.actian.com/.

Comment: Thank you. While I'm at it, could you briefly explain the process for connecting to a remote server Pervasive ODBC data source and using it in my application?

Thanks!

Comment: Connecting to a Pervasive database is a whole other question. It's hard to give a "brief" explanation because there are so many variables (language, interface, platform, etc).

Comment: Where now can we download the Pervasive database client for Linux (especially version 13)?